# area of triangle using command line in c language

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    float height,base,area;
    if(argc>=1){
        printf("%s %s",argv[1],argv[2]);
        height=atof(argv[1]);
        base=atof(argv[2]);
        area=(height*base)/2;
        printf("%f, %f, %.2f",height,base,area);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This c code take the average value of the height and base when I convert the code in float using `atof()` function of c on my computer, but some how on my friend's computer the code work properly. Why is this?

Comment: Use proper formatting, tag correctly (C or C++ but not both in most cases), and how about asking a question?

Comment: What *"garbage value"* are you talking about?

Comment: How are you running this program?

Comment: `argc>=1` is not matching what you should actually expect.

Comment: `argc` is always at least 1.

Comment: And `atof()` always return a valid `float`.

Comment: This question is going to be closed as non-reproducible, if no further information is added.

Comment: `if(argc>=1)` ==> `if(argc >= 3)`

Comment: @molbdnilo Disagree with [argc is always at least 1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330716/area-of-triangle-using-command-line-in-c-language#comment79622347_46330716)  That is not support by the C spec which has "The value of argc shall be nonnegative." and "If the value of argc is greater than zero, ..."

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you forgot to include stdlib.h and you're not getting the right return type of atof as a double.  Always look at all of the warnings your compiler gives you.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    double height,base,area;
    if(argc==3){
        printf("%s %s\n",argv[1],argv[2]);
        height=atof(argv[1]);
        base=atof(argv[2]);
        area=(height*base)/2;
        printf("%f, %f, %.2f",height,base,area);
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage:\n\t%s height base\n",argv[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDBboQgEIbvPgVxs4luWGvd7KXWvkXTQ/UwIiAJxQ1gL82@eimg2a4tCTCZ@edjfsiRE@LcTigi54GiZ2MHKfpifEk2OTGFVCKURR8gVBYC0JxgMoJGBx9@vnf5V4L8Gqa5lxSNVPDR4h4MxaAp1LEoWBb6mua0qsO6aM9jWbo3aG9aleLIe@yWu@ry@iZdqA3YKYKC6q4aHrurbTrDDE229B@CMH@o6v8jMIziLiqW4r8eVtw1nlQa@uuBrQT/WVRrnL4a4PSpVa31rhZOHO9mr@w2NE3trBUq6@TqnIOBgTsVpTsX5TdhErhxxzeQ8gc)

Comment: Forgot `#include <stdio.h>` too.

Comment: `argc>=1` --> `argc>=3`  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330716/area-of-triangle-using-command-line-in-c-language#comment79622717_46330716)

Comment: @chux now it prints usage too :-)